# Wake-up from Deep Power-Down mode causes a reset in LPC1768

Tags: sleep, cortex-m

I need to minimize the current consumption in my board which uses a LPC1768. Now I don't have any problem with going into Deep Sleep or Power-Down modes and waking up from those modes. I have configured the RTC to generate an interrupt after some predefined time which does wake up the MCU correctly and works just fine.

My problem occurs when I want to go into Deep Power-Down mode which is precisely what I need (its consumes much less power). But after generating the RTC Interrupt the MCU goes into a reset state and starts the execution from the beginning as if someone pushes the reset button!
Now why is that? I read from the documents (like this example: [AN10915: Using the LPC1700 power modes](https://www.lpcware.com/content/nxpfile/an10915-using-lpc1700-power-modes-0)) that these three routines are pretty much the same.

I don't understand. There should be no problem according to the example.
I really need to do this otherwise we loose the battery sooner than it is supposed to.

Comment: To quote the manual: _"In Deep Power-down mode, power is shut off to the entire chip with the exception of the Real-Time Clock, the RESET pin, the WIC, and the RTC backup registers"_. I would surmise that the CPU state and SRAM are part of "the entire chip", thus that this is probably the expected behaviour.

Comment: Ok. My problem was solved. Apparently this is what is supposed to happen when you enter Deep Power-Down mode. And also you loose all SRAM contents! Damn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UM10360.pdf, chapter 4.8.4 says: "In Deep Power-down mode, power is shut off to the entire chip" [...]

That means all data that is not in the RTC backup registers is lost, and the chip will thus restart with a reset.

Comment: Thank you. I just realized by going into Deep Power-Down mode all of SRAM contents are gone for good. I have to use a flash or something to store my important variables.